# What's the difference between ✱chrome or chrome✱?

Tags: g1ant

I had tried both ✱chrome and chrome✱, both the time it opens up the chrome window. Now I am confused that how ✱ works?

```
    window ✱chrome
```

or

```
    window chrome✱
```

Comment: Relevant parts of documentation: [search place](https://manual.g1ant.com/appendices/special-characters/search-place.md) and [window](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.Core/Commands/WindowCommand.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window ✱chrome` will wait for a window with a title that **ends with** "chrome" and bring it to the front.

`window chrome✱` will wait for a window with a title that **starts with** "chrome" and bring it to the front.

`✱` sign means any string of characters. As @Nick A the Popcorn King suggests, you can visit  [search place](https://manual.g1ant.com/appendices/special-characters/search-place.md) and [window](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.Core/Commands/WindowCommand.md) descriptions in the manual to get more information about them.